# Trouble interfacing PN5180 RFID Module with Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, rfid

I bought the PN5180 module a few weeks back and I am having quite a bit of trouble interfacing it with my Arduino Uno. The library that I am using is ATrappmann PN5180 Library. The link of which is here https://github.com/ATrappmann/PN5180-Library. I have followed his connections to the letter and have tested each component individually.
The Uno is fine since I have used it extensively for other testing. The Level Shifter is also working fine. The one I am using is similar to [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.daraz.pk%2Fproducts%2Flogic-shifter-i196276735.html&psig=AOvVaw1dmpmv3R7k6qsGQNMAiIqE&ust=1626208643777000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAoQjRxqFwoTCJivprWx3vECFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD). The jumper wires are also fine. I have tried working with both examples given in the library and the code gets stuck during the looping. I have attached a screenshot here.

[image]

I can't seem to figure out where is it going wrong. Is there any way I can use the RC522 Library for setting up the PN5180 reader? I have successfully integrated both RC522 and PN532 NFC readers with Uno but they don't have the required range. I plan on using the reader for localization. It will read the cards and compare it with an array of UID characters to figure out where it is. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated honestly!

Edit:
Adding the circuit diagram and code so that It is easier to understand

[image]

Code:

```
// NAME: PN5180-Library.ino
//
// DESC: Example usage of the PN5180 library for the PN5180-NFC Module
//       from NXP Semiconductors.
//
// Copyright (c) 2018 by Andreas Trappmann. All rights reserved.
//
// This file is part of the PN5180 library for the Arduino environment.
//
// This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
// modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
// License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
// version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
//
// This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
// but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
// MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU
// Lesser General Public License for more details.
//
// BEWARE: SPI with an Arduino to a PN5180 module has to be at a level of 3.3V
// use of logic-level converters from 5V->3.3V is absolutely necessary
// on most Arduinos for all input pins of PN5180!
// If used with an ESP-32, there is no need for a logic-level converter, since
// it operates on 3.3V already.
//
// Arduino <-> Level Converter <-> PN5180 pin mapping:
// 5V             <-->             5V
// 3.3V           <-->             3.3V
// GND            <-->             GND
// 5V      <-> HV
// GND     <-> GND (HV)
//             LV              <-> 3.3V
//             GND (LV)        <-> GND
// SCLK,13 <-> HV1 - LV1       --> SCLK
// MISO,12        <---         <-- MISO
// MOSI,11 <-> HV3 - LV3       --> MOSI
// SS,10   <-> HV4 - LV4       --> NSS (=Not SS -> active LOW)
// BUSY,9         <---             BUSY
// Reset,7 <-> HV2 - LV2       --> RST
//
// ESP-32    <--> PN5180 pin mapping:
// 3.3V      <--> 3.3V
// GND       <--> GND
// SCLK, 18   --> SCLK
// MISO, 19  <--  MISO
// MOSI, 23   --> MOSI
// SS, 16     --> NSS (=Not SS -> active LOW)
// BUSY, 5   <--  BUSY
// Reset, 17  --> RST
//

/*
 * Pins on ICODE2 Reader Writer:
 *
 *   ICODE2   |     PN5180
 * pin  label | pin  I/O  name
 * 1    +5V
 * 2    +3,3V
 * 3    RST     10   I    RESET_N (low active)
 * 4    NSS     1    I    SPI NSS
 * 5    MOSI    3    I    SPI MOSI
 * 6    MISO    5    O    SPI MISO
 * 7    SCK     7    I    SPI Clock
 * 8    BUSY    8    O    Busy Signal
 * 9    GND     9  Supply VSS - Ground
 * 10   GPIO    38   O    GPO1 - Control for external DC/DC
 * 11   IRQ     39   O    IRQ
 * 12   AUX     40   O    AUX1 - Analog/Digital test signal
 * 13   REQ     2?  I/O   AUX2 - Analog test bus or download
 *
 */

//#define WRITE_ENABLED 1

#include <PN5180.h>
#include <PN5180ISO15693.h>

#if defined(ARDUINO_AVR_UNO) || defined(ARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560) || defined(ARDUINO_AVR_NANO)

#define PN5180_NSS  10
#define PN5180_BUSY 9
#define PN5180_RST  7

#elif defined(ARDUINO_ARCH_ESP32)

#define PN5180_NSS  16
#define PN5180_BUSY 5
#define PN5180_RST  17

#else
#error Please define your pinout here!
#endif

PN5180ISO15693 nfc(PN5180_NSS, PN5180_BUSY, PN5180_RST);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println(F("=================================="));
  Serial.println(F("Uploaded: " __DATE__ " " __TIME__));
  Serial.println(F("PN5180 ISO15693 Demo Sketch"));

  nfc.begin();

  Serial.println(F("----------------------------------"));
  Serial.println(F("PN5180 Hard-Reset..."));
  nfc.reset();

  Serial.println(F("----------------------------------"));
  Serial.println(F("Reading product version..."));
  uint8_t productVersion[2];
  nfc.readEEprom(PRODUCT_VERSION, productVersion, sizeof(productVersion));
  Serial.print(F("Product version="));
  Serial.print(productVersion[1]);
  Serial.print(".");
  Serial.println(productVersion[0]);

  if (0xff == productVersion[1]) { // if product version 255, the initialization failed
    Serial.println(F("Initialization failed!?"));
    Serial.println(F("Press reset to restart..."));
    Serial.flush();
    exit(-1); // halt
  }
  
  Serial.println(F("----------------------------------"));
  Serial.println(F("Reading firmware version..."));
  uint8_t firmwareVersion[2];
  nfc.readEEprom(FIRMWARE_VERSION, firmwareVersion, sizeof(firmwareVersion));
  Serial.print(F("Firmware version="));
  Serial.print(firmwareVersion[1]);
  Serial.print(".");
  Serial.println(firmwareVersion[0]);

  Serial.println(F("----------------------------------"));
  Serial.println(F("Reading EEPROM version..."));
  uint8_t eepromVersion[2];
  nfc.readEEprom(EEPROM_VERSION, eepromVersion, sizeof(eepromVersion));
  Serial.print(F("EEPROM version="));
  Serial.print(eepromVersion[1]);
  Serial.print(".");
  Serial.println(eepromVersion[0]);

  /*
  Serial.println(F("----------------------------------"));
  Serial.println(F("Reading IRQ pin config..."));
  uint8_t irqConfig;
  nfc.readEEprom(IRQ_PIN_CONFIG, &irqConfig, 1));
  Serial.print(F("IRQ_PIN_CONFIG=0x"));
  Serial.println(irqConfig, HEX);

  Serial.println(F("----------------------------------"));
  Serial.println(F("Reading IRQ_ENABLE register..."));
  uint32_t irqEnable;
  nfc.readRegister(IRQ_ENABLE, &irqEnable));
  Serial.print(F("IRQ_ENABLE=0x"));
  Serial.println(irqConfig, HEX);
  */

  Serial.println(F("----------------------------------"));
  Serial.println(F("Enable RF field..."));
  nfc.setupRF();
}

uint32_t loopCnt = 0;
bool errorFlag = false;

void loop() {
  if (errorFlag) {
    uint32_t irqStatus = nfc.getIRQStatus();
    showIRQStatus(irqStatus);

    if (0 == (RX_SOF_DET_IRQ_STAT & irqStatus)) { // no card detected
      Serial.println(F("*** No card detected!"));
    }

    nfc.reset();
    nfc.setupRF();

    errorFlag = false;
  }

  Serial.println(F("----------------------------------"));
  Serial.print(F("Loop #"));
  Serial.println(loopCnt++);

/*
  // code for unlocking an ICODE SLIX2 protected tag   
  uint8_t password[] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04}; // put your privacy password here
  ISO15693ErrorCode myrc = nfc.unlockICODESLIX2(password);
  if (ISO15693_EC_OK == myrc) {
    Serial.println("unlockICODESLIX2 successful");
  }
*/
  
  uint8_t uid[8];
  ISO15693ErrorCode rc = nfc.getInventory(uid);
  if (ISO15693_EC_OK != rc) {
    Serial.print(F("Error in getInventory: "));
    Serial.println(nfc.strerror(rc));
    errorFlag = true;
    return;
  }
  Serial.print(F("Inventory successful, UID="));
  for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
    Serial.print(uid[7-i], HEX); // LSB is first
    if (i < 2) Serial.print(":");
  }
  Serial.println();

  Serial.println(F("----------------------------------"));
  uint8_t blockSize, numBlocks;
  rc = nfc.getSystemInfo(uid, &blockSize, &numBlocks);
  if (ISO15693_EC_OK != rc) {
    Serial.print(F("Error in getSystemInfo: "));
    Serial.println(nfc.strerror(rc));
    errorFlag = true;
    return;
  }
  Serial.print(F("System Info retrieved: blockSize="));
  Serial.print(blockSize);
  Serial.print(F(", numBlocks="));
  Serial.println(numBlocks);

  Serial.println(F("----------------------------------"));
  uint8_t readBuffer[blockSize];
  for (int no=0; no<numBlocks; no++) {
    rc = nfc.readSingleBlock(uid, no, readBuffer, blockSize);
    if (ISO15693_EC_OK != rc) {
      Serial.print(F("Error in readSingleBlock #"));
      Serial.print(no);
      Serial.print(": ");
      Serial.println(nfc.strerror(rc));
      errorFlag = true;
      return;
    }
    Serial.print(F("Read block #"));
    Serial.print(no);
    Serial.print(": ");
    for (int i=0; i<blockSize; i++) {
      if (readBuffer[i] < 16) Serial.print("0");
      Serial.print(readBuffer[i], HEX);
      Serial.print(" ");
    }
    Serial.print(" ");
    for (int i=0; i<blockSize; i++) {
      if (isprint(readBuffer[i])) {
        Serial.print((char)readBuffer[i]);
      }
      else Serial.print(".");
    }
    Serial.println();
  }

#ifdef WRITE_ENABLED
  Serial.println(F("----------------------------------"));
  uint8_t *writeBuffer = malloc(blockSize);
  for (int i=0; i<blockSize; i++) {
    writeBuffer[i] = 0x80 + i;
  }
  for (int no=0; no<numBlocks; no++) {
    rc = nfc.writeSingleBlock(uid, no, writeBuffer, blockSize);
    if (ISO15693_EC_OK == rc) {
      Serial.print(F("Wrote block #"));
      Serial.println(no);
    }
    else {
      Serial.print(F("Error in writeSingleBlock #"));
      Serial.print(no);
      Serial.print(": ");
      Serial.println(nfc.strerror(rc));
      errorFlag = true;
      return;
    }
  }
#endif /* WRITE_ENABLED */

/*
  // code for locking an ICODE SLIX2 protected tag   
  ISO15693ErrorCode myrc = nfc.lockICODESLIX2(password);
  if (ISO15693_EC_OK == myrc) {
    Serial.println("lockICODESLIX2 successful");
    delay(5000);
*/
  delay(1000);
}

void showIRQStatus(uint32_t irqStatus) {
  Serial.print(F("IRQ-Status 0x"));
  Serial.print(irqStatus, HEX);
  Serial.print(": [ ");
  if (irqStatus & (1<< 0)) Serial.print(F("RQ "));
  if (irqStatus & (1<< 1)) Serial.print(F("TX "));
  if (irqStatus & (1<< 2)) Serial.print(F("IDLE "));
  if (irqStatus & (1<< 3)) Serial.print(F("MODE_DETECTED "));
  if (irqStatus & (1<< 4)) Serial.print(F("CARD_ACTIVATED "));
  if (irqStatus & (1<< 5)) Serial.print(F("STATE_CHANGE "));
  if (irqStatus & (1<< 6)) Serial.print(F("RFOFF_DET "));
  if (irqStatus & (1<< 7)) Serial.print(F("RFON_DET "));
  if (irqStatus & (1<< 8)) Serial.print(F("TX_RFOFF "));
  if (irqStatus & (1<< 9)) Serial.print(F("TX_RFON "));
  if (irqStatus & (1<<10)) Serial.print(F("RF_ACTIVE_ERROR "));
  if (irqStatus & (1<<11)) Serial.print(F("TIMER0 "));
  if (irqStatus & (1<<12)) Serial.print(F("TIMER1 "));
  if (irqStatus & (1<<13)) Serial.print(F("TIMER2 "));
  if (irqStatus & (1<<14)) Serial.print(F("RX_SOF_DET "));
  if (irqStatus & (1<<15)) Serial.print(F("RX_SC_DET "));
  if (irqStatus & (1<<16)) Serial.print(F("TEMPSENS_ERROR "));
  if (irqStatus & (1<<17)) Serial.print(F("GENERAL_ERROR "));
  if (irqStatus & (1<<18)) Serial.print(F("HV_ERROR "));
  if (irqStatus & (1<<19)) Serial.print(F("LPCD "));
  Serial.println("]");
}
```

Edit 2:

So i tried one of the forks of ATrappmann library. the link is https://github.com/tueddy/PN5180-Library, and the problem of the code stalling at loops have been resolved. But now, the reader won't read any of my cards :(

Comment: I have the same problem as you, have you solved it ????.